# Reassign dictionary key values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary

```
brands = {
1: 'BPR Performance Rimfire',
2: 'M22',
3: 'M22 Subsonic',
4: 'Super Suppressed',
5: 'Super X',
6: 'USA',
7: 'Varmint HE',
8: 'Varmint LF',
9: 'Wildcat',
10: 'Xpert', }
```

and depending on some user selection I want to display a subset of this dictionary in the form of a menu, which I can do but I would like to update the keys so that if I'm only showing three elements such as

```
1 -- BPR Performance Rimfire
5 -- Super X
7 -- Varmint HE
```

I could reassign the number corresponding to the option, for example

```
1 -- BPR Performance Rimfire
2 -- Super X
3 -- Varmint HE
```

To do so, I have made these two functions

```
def entries_to_remove(entries, dictionary):
    for key in entries:
        if key in dictionary:
            del dictionary[key]

def update_keys(dictionary):
    dict_copy = dictionary.copy()
    key_n = 1
    for k in dictionary:
        dict_copy[key_n] = dict_copy.pop(k)
        key_n = key_n + 1
    return dict_copy
```

then I define the entries to remove, which works

```
entries = (2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10)
entries_to_remove(entries, brands)
```

and then call

```
brands = update_keys(brands)
```

which gives me an error in the function entries_to_remove

```
  File "C:\Users\teide\Documents\Guns\moa_clicks.py", line 70, in addBullet
entries_to_remove(entries, brands)
                           ^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'brands' where it is not associated with a value
```

If I comment out `brands = update_keys(brands)` the code executes normally and gives me the expected result

```
Choose brand
1 -- BPR Performance Rimfire
5 -- Super X
7 -- Varmint HE
8 -- Varmint LF
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and some help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm adding the full code that I have at the moment

```
menu_options = {
    1: 'Add bullet type',
    2: 'Calculate MOA clicks',
    3: 'Exit',
}

cartridge_types = {
    1: '17 HMR',
    2: '17 Win Super Mag',
    3: '22 Long',
    4: '22 Long Rifle',
    5: '22 Short',
    6: '22 Win Mag',
    7: '22 WRF',
}

brands = {
    1: 'BPR Performance Rimfire',
    2: 'M22',
    3: 'M22 Subsonic',
    4: 'Super Suppressed',
    5: 'Super X',
    6: 'USA',
    7: 'Varmint HE',
    8: 'Varmint LF',
    9: 'Wildcat',
    10: 'Xpert',
}
      
def print_menu(menu):
    for key in menu.keys():
        print (key, '--', menu[key] )  
        

def entries_to_remove(entries, dictionary):
    for key in entries:
        if key in dictionary:
            del dictionary[key]

def update_keys(dictionary):
    dict_copy = dictionary.copy()
    key_n = 1
    for k in dictionary:
        dict_copy[key_n] = dict_copy.pop(k)
        key_n = key_n + 1
    return dict_copy

def addBullet():  
        name = str(input('Enter bullet name: '))
        print('Choose cartridge type')
        print_menu(cartridge_types)
        cType = cartridge_types.get(int(input()))
        if cType == cartridge_types.get(1):
            entries = (2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10)
            entries_to_remove(entries, brands)
            #brands = update_keys(brands)
            
        print('Choose brand')
        print_menu(brands)
        brand = brands.get(int(input()))
        


while(True):
    print_menu(menu_options)
    option = int(input('Enter your choice: ')) 
    if option == 1:
        addBullet()
    elif option == 2:
        calculateMOA()
    elif option == 3:
        print('Goodbye')
        exit()
    else:
        print('Invalid option. Please enter a number between 1 and 3.')
```

Comment: The error you're encountering is because you are trying to access the brands dictionary inside the addBullet function, but you haven't declared it as a global variable within the function.

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary when the keys are sequential numbers? Use a list. Then you don't have to reindex it when you add and remove elements.

Comment: @Barmar right, I should have said that I'm doing this with dictionaries because I'm doing practice with dictionaries.

Comment: Even if you want to use dictionaries, there’s no point in copying the whole thing only to replace its contents entirely.

Comment: @DavisHerring so this could be done dynamically on the same dictionary? Like dictionary[key_n] = dictionary.pop(k)

Comment: @Francesco: I meant you could just create a new, empty dictionary and add the desired values under the new keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `addBullet` function to use the `brands` dictionary correctly:

```py
def addBullet():
    global brands  # Declare brands as a global variable
    name = str(input('Enter bullet name: '))
    print('Choose cartridge type')
    print_menu(cartridge_types)
    cType = cartridge_types.get(int(input()))
    if cType == cartridge_types.get(1):
        entries = (2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10)
        entries_to_remove(entries, brands)
        brands = update_keys(brands)  # Update the global brands dictionary
    print('Choose brand')
    print_menu(brands)
    brand = brands.get(int(input()))
```

Now, when you call `brands = update_keys(brands)` inside the function, it should work without any errors, and your `brands` dictionary will be updated with the modified keys as you intended.

Update: I agree with @barmar comment. You should use list.